# How to combine type import and value import in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have these two import statements

```js
import type { SomeType } from 'someFile'
import { ValueA, ValueB } from 'someFile'
```

Can I combine them in one statement like below?

```js
import { type SomeType, ValueA, ValueB } from 'someFile'
```

I tried the second approach and it run successfully. But I'm not sure whether this is correct or not. Because I could not find any single example similar to this one in the internet.

Comment: I think this is a matter of choice. You should stick with either one in all of your files. Also check popular code formatters to see how they keep it.

Comment: check the discussions here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39861